# Saving master detail entities

Tags: hibernate

I have a small invoicing app where I have (InvoiceMaster) and (InvoiceDetails) entities, now I am facing a problem on how to save the Master and Details together in the same time / in other words in one transaction...

I already have the following classes in my application:

```
- InvoiceMasterDAO
- InvoiceDetailsDAO

- InvoiceMasterService
- InvoiceDetailsService
```

and I was thinking shall I call the InvoiceMasterDAO, InvoiceDetailsDAO save method from within the InvoiceMasterService class? But if I did this then there is no use for the InvoiceDetailsService class?

OR Shall I just create an InvoiceService class and use to to control both InvoiceMasterDAO, InvoiceDetailsDAO in the same time?

Taking in consideration that saving an invoice for me means, saving master, saving details, deducting product balances.....OR rollback everything in case something went wront

Kindly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you, but having an `InvoiceService` looks like the more logical to me.

Services shouldn't be designed as one service per entity. They should be designed as a logical group of ... services that the caller needs (the UI layer, usually). In other words, they should be use-case oriented, and not entity-oriented.